# Object property with strong reference becomes null

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

A key of an array that's set on a property on another object (`dataController` in `BWMasterViewController`) with a strong reference becomes `null`. I don't understand why.

## BWMasterViewController

header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class BWBirdSightingDataController;

@interface BWMasterViewController : UITableViewController
@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "BWMasterViewController.h"
#import "BWBirdSightingDataController.h"
#import "Bird.h"
#import "BWWebviewController.h"

@interface BWMasterViewController()
@property (strong, nonatomic) BWBirdSightingDataController *dataController;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *test;
@end

@implementation BWMasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{

    [super awakeFromNib];

    NSLog(@"awake from nib");
    self.dataController = [[BWBirdSightingDataController alloc] init];
    self.test = @"Test var";

    NSLog(@"test: %@", self.test);
    Bird *bird = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"bird object: %@", bird);
    NSLog(@"bird name: %@", bird.name)

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"view did load");

    NSLog(@"test: %@", self.test);
    Bird *bird = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"bird object: %@", bird);
    NSLog(@"bird name: %@", bird.name)

}

// ....
```

## BWBirdSightingDataController

header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Bird;

@interface BWBirdSightingDataController : NSObject
- (NSUInteger)countOfList;
- (Bird *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex;
@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "BWBirdSightingDataController.h"
#import "BWDataController.h"
#import "Bird.h"

@interface BWBirdSightingDataController ()
-(void)initializeDefaultDataList;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *birds;
@end

@implementation BWBirdSightingDataController

- (id)init
{

    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self initializeDefaultDataList];
        return self;
    }

    return nil;

}

- (void)initializeDefaultDataList
{

    BWDataController *dataController = [[BWDataController alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *birdsEntity = [NSEntityDescription
                                        entityForName:@"Bird"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:dataController.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchBirds = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchBirds setEntity:birdsEntity];

    NSError *fetchError = nil;
    NSArray *birdsObjects = [dataController.managedObjectContext
                             executeFetchRequest:fetchBirds
                             error:&fetchError];
    self.birds = [birdsObjects mutableCopy];

}

- (NSUInteger)countOfList
{
    return [self.birds count];
}

- (Bird *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex
{
    return self.birds[theIndex];
}

@end
```

## Bird

Bird is a `NSManagedObject` based on a CoreData Entity.

header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Bird : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * url;

@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "Bird.h"


@implementation Bird

@dynamic date;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic location;
@dynamic image;
@dynamic url;

@end
```

## Output

When I run it, this outputs:

```
2013-05-31 11:36:47.824 BirdWatching[69565:c07] awake from nib
2013-05-31 11:36:47.834 BirdWatching[69565:c07] test: Test var
2013-05-31 11:36:47.834 BirdWatching[69565:c07] bird object: <Bird: 0x8545ec0> (entity: Bird; id: 0x8545040 <x-coredata://D24A664F-8E8F-4AF0-891C-098C8A7DD860/Bird/p1> ; data: <fault>)
2013-05-31 11:36:47.835 BirdWatching[69565:c07] bird name: Pigeon
2013-05-31 11:36:47.839 BirdWatching[69565:c07] view did load
2013-05-31 11:36:47.840 BirdWatching[69565:c07] test: Test var
2013-05-31 11:36:47.840 BirdWatching[69565:c07] bird object: <Bird: 0x8545ec0> (entity: Bird; id: 0x8545040 <x-coredata://D24A664F-8E8F-4AF0-891C-098C8A7DD860/Bird/p1> ; data: <fault>)
2013-05-31 11:36:47.840 BirdWatching[69565:c07] bird name: (null)
```

So as you can see, in the `viewDidLoad` function the bird.name has become null. How come? I declared the property as a strong reference.

I have the same problem when I would define `self.dataController` in `viewDidLoad`, then it would be null in `prepareForSegue`, where I also need it.

Comment: Show your code of BWBirdSightingDataController

Comment: Add more logging or use the debugger to step through your code. Frequently check if `self.birds` is not nil. I suspect that the entire array becomes invalid.

Comment: That's really weird. Instead of the `bird` variable, could you print out `self.dataController` as well? And inside `-objectInListAtIndex:`, could you print out `self.birds`?

Comment: Any reason why the NSMutableArray of birds in the BWBirdSightingDataController is set to 'copy'?  Why aren't you strongly referencing this?

Comment: @Till Now I'm also logging the `bird` object + `bird.name`. See the updated output

Comment: @rednaw, aha - so the bird stays valid but it loses its name... So the problem is somewhere within code / definitions that you did now show us.

Comment: @Tim changed it to strong but same result

Comment: @Till yes, apparently, but why?

Comment: You'll have to show us the `Bird` class.

Comment: Could it be that the managed object context (dataController.managedObjectContext) has been deallocated in the meantime? A managed object can only live in a context. If the context of an object is destroyed then exactly that happens: All properties return nil.

Comment: Can you try `self.birds=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:birdsObjects copyItems:YES]` instead of creating a `mutableCopy`? And make `self.birds` as `strong` array?

Comment: @Amar I get an error at runtime: `-[Bird copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x815efb0`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You create the `Bird` objects in `initializeDefaultDataList` using the local `BWDataController *dataController`. `dataController` is automatically deallocated at the end of this method, which probably means that the managed object context `dataController.managedObjectContext` also no longer exist.

However, a managed object can only live in the context that it was created in. If the context is destroyed then exactly that happens: Accessing all properties returns `nil`.

Possible solutions:

- Make `dataController` a strong property of `BWBirdSightingDataController` instead of a local variable.
- Use a shared managed object context across the application.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. So how can I retain these `Bird` objects in my `birds` property? I was thinking I can have `BWBirdSightingDataController` manage the communication with Core Data, safe the required data internally and serve it to `BWMasterViewController`. How would I go about that?

Comment: Yeah, I made `dataController` a strong property, now it works! Thanks!

Comment: +1 but note that *"Use a shared managed object context across the application"* in this scenario implies that the MOC should be created on the main thread and interactions with the MOC should be on the main thread.